# The Secret Meeting

Tags: cipher, knowledge

In a special operation our unit was able to intercept encrypted chat messages from a group of spies who plan a secret meeting:

[image: chat]

> Ifmmp fwfszpof!
>   Jk
>   Krzgb
>   Wyt?
>   Fwj dtz htrnsl yt ymj Sjb Djfw'x ufwyd?
>   Ekgn, ul iuaxyk, oz'rr hk gckyusk!
>   Ylhssf nbfz? Aopz pz hu lujyfwalk jvuclyzpvu mvy ptwvyahua tlzzhnlz vusf
>   Ws Jwaa
>   R anvrwm hxd fn wnnm cx bnc dy j crvn oxa cqn wngc vnncrwp
>   S mkx'd Deocnkic kpdob 7
>   Hsle lmzfe esp qtcde Hpoypdolj zq esp xzyes?
>   Omz'f, uf'e yk mzzuhqdemdk
>   Znmny gbi
>   Hvoby Mci
>   Rpc ndj rdbt dc iwt 20iw?
>   De, Y xqlu qd unqc.
>   Fb, kyrk cvrmvj lj nzky fecp fev fgkzfe.
>   Usf wnwjqgfw  escw al?
>   Rxl
>   Syj
>   Hz ojj.
>   Cnawp, oaa ukq pdaj!
>   Yvb!

We also acquired this note from a secret agent:

[image: note1]

> *Bitcoin encoding:*
>   3mM4jWTdh6qrGP
>   3mM4japbLpuUij
>   3mM4ENFbwtRhwk
>   3mM4jYf77P5oVZ
>   3mM4jWSeGPL3VR

**Can you decrypt the messages and find when the spies are meeting?**

**Hint 1:**

> Our intel says that each line in the note indicates a different time, possibly for the meeting, but we still need to decode it first.

**Hint 2:**

> The forensics team just found out that there was something written in invisible ink on the other side of the note:
>
>  [image: note2]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Continuing on from QuantumTwinkie's answer...

For the Bitcoin Encoding:

> [image]

The Meeting will be on:

> Sunday January 13, 2019 at 20:30

Useful Resources:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58
>  https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Nice job! +1 ...

Comment: Explanation of how you got that table?

Comment: @Barker - What do you mean?  I added some useful resources in the post,

Comment: Basically what [Annosz's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79643/42302) does.  They go through how they went from the phrase "Bitcoin encoding" to the solution. Your answer just has the table out of nowhere and I didn't understand where it came from until I read Annosz's answer.

Answer (score 12):

For the beginning

> You start with rot25 for the first line, then continue down one rot for each line to get:
>  **Hello everyone!
> Hi
> Howdy
>  Sup?
> Are you coming to the New Year's party?
> Yeah, of course, it'll be awesome!
> Really guys? This is an encrypted conversion for important messages only
> Ok Boss
> I remind you we need to set up a time for the next meeting
> I can't Tuesdays after 7
> What about the first Wednesday of the month?
> Can't, it's my anniversary
> Mazal tov
> Thank You
> Can you come on the 20th?
> No, I have an exam.
> Ok, that leaves us with only one option.
> Can everyone make it?
> Yes
> Yep
> Me Too.
> Great See you then!
> Bye!**

So,

> I can assume that the "current date" is in Decembers as they are anticipating a New Years party. I am also guessing that it is before December 20th since that date is still in the question.

Comment: They are planning the meeting for a specific date which you need to find (and it relates to the note).

Answer (score 6):

We can suspect from Hint2:

> The number 01011970 is reffering to the starting date of the Unix time, or POSIX time, 1970. 01. 01.
> UNIX time is measured as seconds elapsed since this specific date.

Whit this information, we can deyrypt the note's front page

> Bitcoin encoding refers to Base58 encoding. With a decoder, we can see the original information written on the notes: 
> 3mM4jWTdh6qrGP -> 1546452000
> 3mM4japbLpuUij -> 1548009000
> 3mM4ENFbwtRhwk -> 1515529527
> 3mM4jYf77P5oVZ -> 1547411400
> 3mM4jWSeGPL3VR -> 1546282800

These, together with the back

> must mean seconds: giving them to the UNIX start date we get the following times:
> 2019. January 2. 18:00:00
> 2019. January 20. 18:30:00
> 2018. January 9. 20:25:27
> 2019. January 13. 20:30:00
> 2018. December 31. 19:00:00

From the conversation, which was decoded by @QuantumTwinkie, we can

> eliminate the dates that are not good for the meeting: 
> New Year's party is off, so not December 31.
> Tuesdays after 7 pm are off, so not January 9.
> Not the first Wednesday of the month, so not January 2.
> The 20th is off, so not January 20.

The day of the meeting is

> 2019. January 13. 20:30:00

Comment: I know @LeppyR64 was faster than me, but this is the first more complex puzzle I was able to solve on PSE, and I just didn't have the heart to delete it right away :(

Comment: Great work!  Congratulations!

Comment: Nice work! ....